# How would I convert multiple hashes within an array which is contained in another hash to organized strings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have this information that I am trying to display in a CLI upon entering the name of a beer, and the ingredients list shows as follows:

```
h = {
  Ingredients: {
    "malt"=>[
      {"name"=>"Extra Pale", "amount"=>{"value"=>4.58, "unit"=>"kilograms"}},
      {"name"=>"Caramalt", "amount"=>{"value"=>0.25, "unit"=>"kilograms"}},
      {"name"=>"Dark Crystal", "amount"=>{"value"=>0.06, "unit"=>"kilograms"}},
      {"name"=>"Munich", "amount"=>{"value"=>0.25, "unit"=>"kilograms"}}
    ],
    "hops"=>[
      {"name"=>"Centennial", "amount"=>{"value"=>5, "unit"=>"grams"},
       "add"=>"start", "attribute"=>"bitter"},
      {"name"=>"Amarillo", "amount"=>{"value"=>5, "unit"=>"grams"},
       "add"=>"start", "attribute"=>"bitter"},
      {"name"=>"Centennial", "amount"=>{"value"=>10, "unit"=>"grams"},
       "add"=>"middle", "attribute"=>"flavour"},
      {"name"=>"Amarillo", "amount"=>{"value"=>10, "unit"=>"grams"},
       "add"=>"middle", "attribute"=>"flavour"},
      {"name"=>"Centennial", "amount"=>{"value"=>17.5, "unit"=>"grams"},
       "add"=>"end", "attribute"=>"flavour"},
      {"name"=>"Amarillo", "amount"=>{"value"=>17.5, "unit"=>"grams"},
       "add"=>"end", "attribute"=>"flavour"}
    ],
    "yeast"=>"Wyeast 2007 - Pilsen Lager™"
  }
}
```

How would I go about turning all of these hashes into neatly displayed strings so that it is easily readable?
I have already created class Ingredient, Malt and Hops, but having difficulty joining them properly as well

Comment: Considering that you are new to SO I suggest you have a look at its [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pp` on a hash to "pretty print" it in a slightly nicer way where it has indentation but it would still have all the characters like `=>` and whatnot. If you want to make it more human readable then you can just use cycle through the elements and use the "puts" command. You can add "\t" to add a tab character that will align things in a more neat fashion in your output. So for example, say your hash there was stored in a variable called `ingredients` you could do something like this:

```rb
ingredients.keys.each do |ingredient_name|
  types = ingredients[ingredient_name]
  puts ingredient_name
  if types.respond_to?(:each)
    types.each do |type|
      puts "\t#{type["name"]} (#{type["attribute"] || "no attribute"})"
    end
  else
    puts "\t#{types}"
  end

end
```

which would output:

```
malt
        Extra Pale (no attribute)
        Caramalt (no attribute)
        Dark Crystal (no attribute)
        Munich (no attribute)
hops
        Centennial (bitter)
        Amarillo (bitter)
        Centennial (flavour)
        Amarillo (flavour)
        Centennial (flavour)
        Amarillo (flavour)
yeast
        Wyeast 2007 - Pilsen Lager™
```

Answer (score 0):

**Display information about malt**

First consolidate the malt information.

```
ingredients = h[:Ingredients]
body = ingredients["malt"].map do |g|
  [g["name"], g["amount"]["value"].to_s + ' ' + g["amount"]["unit"]]
end
  #=> [["Extra Pale", "4.58 kilograms"], ["Caramalt", "0.25 kilograms"],
  #    ["Dark Crystal", "0.06 kilograms"], ["Munich", "0.25 kilograms"]]
```

Next determine the lengths of the longest name and the longest weight expression.

```
max_name_len, max_amt_len = body.transpose.map { |a| a.map(&:size).max }
  #=> [12, 14] 
max_name_len
  #=> 12 ("Dark Crystal") 
max_amt_len
  #=> 14 ("4.58 kilograms")
```

We will left-adjust the name in a string of length 12 and right-adjust the weight in a string of length 14, padding with spaces. Between the two we need a separator comprised of, say, 5 spaces:

```
spacer_len = 5
```

We can simply add that to `max_amt_len` (or to `max_name_len`):

```
max_amt_len += spacer_len
  #=> 19 ("     4.58 kilograms")
```

We can now diplay the information.

```
puts "Malts".center(max_name_len + max_amt_len)
puts '-' * (max_name_len +  max_amt_len)
body.each { |name, amt| puts "%s%s" % [name.ljust(max_name_len),
  amt.rjust(max_amt_len)] }
```

This displays the following.

```
             Malts
-------------------------------
Extra Pale       4.58 kilograms
Caramalt         0.25 kilograms
Dark Crystal     0.06 kilograms
Munich           0.25 kilograms
```

See [String#center](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-center), [String#ljust](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-ljust) and [String#rjust](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-rjust).

```
"%s%s" % [name.ljust(max_name_len), amt.rjust(max_amt_len)]
```

can alternatively be written:

```
sprintf("%s%s", name.ljust(max_name_len), amt.rjust(max_amt_len))
```

See [Kernel#sprintf](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf), which documents string formatting directives for both expressions.

**Add column labels and create a method**

Now let's add column labels and put this in a method.

```
def display(title, column_lbls, lbl_adj, body, body_adj, spacer_len)
  spacer = ' ' * spacer_len
  full_body = [column_lbls] + body
  col_widths = full_body.transpose.map { |a| a.map(&:size).max }
  tot_width = col_widths.sum + spacer_len * (col_widths.size-1)
  puts title.center(tot_width)
  puts
  full_body.each_with_index do |a,i|
    col_adj = i.zero? ? lbl_adj : body_adj
    puts (a.each_with_index.map do |s,j|
      w = col_widths[j]
      case col_adj[j]
      when :L
        s.ljust(w)
      when :R
        s.rjust(w)
      when :C
        s.center(w)
      end
    end.join(spacer))
    puts '-' * tot_width if i.zero?
  end
end
```

Specify additional parameters.

```
column_lbls = ["Name", "Amount"]
lbl_adj     = [:C, :C]
body_adj    = [:L, :R]
```

As seen, the columns are to be labelled `"Name"` and `"Amount"` and both are to be centered. As before the body of the first column is to be left-adjusted and the body of the second column is to be right-adjusted. The argument `body` is the array created above.

```
display("Malts", column_lbls, lbl_adj, body, body_adj, 5)
```

displays

```
              Malts             

    Name             Amount    
-------------------------------
Extra Pale       4.58 kilograms
Caramalt         0.25 kilograms
Dark Crystal     0.06 kilograms
Munich           0.25 kilograms
```

**Display information about hops**

```
body = ingredients["hops"].map do |g|
  amt = g["amount"]
  [g["name"], g["add"], g["attribute"],
    amt["value"].to_f.to_s + ' ' + amt["unit"]]
end
  #=> [["Centennial", "start", "bitter", "5.0 grams"],
  #    ["Amarillo", "start", "bitter", "5.0 grams"],
  #    ["Centennial", "middle", "flavour", "10.0 grams"],
  #    ["Amarillo", "middle", "flavour", "10.0 grams"],
  #    ["Centennial", "end", "flavour", "17.5 grams"],
  #    ["Amarillo", "end", "flavour", "17.5 grams"]] 
column_lbls = ["Name", "Add", "Attribute", "Amount"]
lbl_adj     = [:L, :C, :C, :C]
body_adj    = [:L, :C, :C, :R]
```

```
display("Hops", column_lbls, lbl_adj, body, body_adj, 5)
```

displays

```
                       Hops                       

name            Add       Attribute       Amount  
--------------------------------------------------
Centennial     start       bitter        5.0 grams
Amarillo       start       bitter        5.0 grams
Centennial     middle      flavour      10.0 grams
Amarillo       middle      flavour      10.0 grams
Centennial      end        flavour      17.5 grams
Amarillo        end        flavour      17.5 grams
```

**Display information about yeast**

This is straightforward so I will not consider it here.